# ¿Tiene sentido gramatical un condicional construido con el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo y el condicional perfecto?

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo, tiempos-verbales, pretérito, condicional

Me gustaría aclarar una pequeña duda que me surgió el otro día relacionada con los condicionales. *Grosso modo*, hay tres tipos de condicionales: el Tipo 1, que se formaría con la partícula "si" junto con el verbo en presente de indicativo; el Tipo 2, que se formaría con la partícula "si" junto con el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo; y el Tipo 3 que se forma con el "si" más el verbo en pretérito pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo.

Mi pregunta se refiere a cuándo podemos hacer uso del condicional formado por el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo y el condicional perfecto. Por poner un ejemplo, la frase:

> Si vinieras a la fiesta, habrías conocido a María.

No tiene sentido gramatical para mí (no sé si es correcta), y en su lugar yo diría: *Si hubieras venido a la fiesta, habrías conocido a Maria*.
En cambio, la frase:

> Si no supiera manejar correctamente ordenadores, jamás habría conseguido el trabajo.

me suena algo mejor que:

> Si no hubiera sabido manejar correctamente ordenadores, jamás habría conseguido el trabajo.

Ya que al conjugar el emisor el verbo en pretérito pluscuamperfecto, podría dar a entender que en algún momento (en la entrevista), supo manejar ordenadores correctamente, pero ahora no tiene por qué saber manejarlos.

En definitiva, lo que me gustaría aclarar es:
**¿Es posible y tiene sentido gramatical en castellano un condicional formado por la partícula "si" más el verbo en pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo más el verbo en condicional perfecto?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer una analogía con el inglés, esto se conoce como *condicional mixto.*

Estos condicionales mezclan la forma con el pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo con el pluscuamperfecto de subjuntivo y también con la forma condicional presente del verbo y el condicional perfecto.

Su uso se basa en la referencia temporal de lo que se desee expresar ya sea con una situación imaginaria del presente y con un resultado de una acción que no ocurrió en el pasado o viceversa.

Teniendo:

1. Si **no supiera/supiese** manejar correctamente ordenadores, jamás **habría conseguido** el trabajo.

   Esto muestra que la persona **sabe** correctamente manejar los ordenadores, es una situación permanente, y con su implicancia en un punto particular del pasado: la persona **consiguió el trabajo.**
2. Si no **hubiese/hubiera** sabido manejar correctamente ordenadores (...)

   Esto muestra que la persona **supo** manejar los ordenadores en un punto definido del pasado. No sabemos si es permanente, pero sí sabemos de que su implicancia es que consiguió el trabajo.

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias por la respuesta, justo lo que andaba buscando.

Comment: Pensaba que "implicancia" era una forma incorrecta de decir "implicación", pero me equivocaba: es la forma correcta en muchos países. ¡Una cosa nueva que aprendo!

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Aquí se aprende de todo — ¡Esa es la idea!